# Moving user to Exchange in the cloud with a Try/Catch

Tags: powershell

Good day guys,

Background;
There is a script that creates AD users and then it moves them to the cloud. I'm trying to implement some type of failover in the script. The idea would be that in case something happens to the move request like serves, not having time to sync, the script could wait for 3 minutes and send a sync request to the servers then try again.

The issue;
8/10 user move to the cloud without any problems. The problem is with the 2/10. When they fail the Try face, the script goes to the Catch face normally. It waits the 3 minutes and sends the sync request but when trying to run the New-CLMoveRequest I get this error;

"The Mailbox Replication Service was unable to connect to the remote server using the credentials provided. Please check the credentials and try again. 
The call to 'https://webmail.domain.com/EWS/mrsproxy.svc' failed. Error details: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 
'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'. --> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.. --> 
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 
'Negotiate,NTLM'. --> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized."

$Localcred have my credentials and the first time it tries to move the user it takes my cred without issue. For some reason, the second time is like $Localcred  loses my creds.

The questions; What is it that I'm doing wrong? Also, is there any way that I can improve the script?

Thank you for your time

```
 try {
        # Move user to the cloud
        New-CLMoveRequest -identity $ADuserObject.Mailbox `
            -Remote -RemoteHostName 'webmail.Domain.com' `
            -RemoteCredential $Localcred `
            -TargetDeliveryDomain 'Domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com' `
            -BadItemLimit 10 -LargeItemLimit 20 -ErrorAction stop -ErrorVariable ErrorlorLog
    }
    catch {
        # Move user to the cloud  # Wait 3 minutes 
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 180
        Write-Warning "The servers have not sync yet,waiting 90 sec and running sync" 
        # Run a Sync on Office365
        invoke-command -computername "ComputerName" {start-adsyncsynccycle -policytype delta};
        # Move user to the cloud
        New-CLMoveRequest -identity $ADuserObject.Mailbox `
            -Remote -RemoteHostName 'webmail.domain.com' `
            -RemoteCredential $Localcred `
            -TargetDeliveryDomain 'domain.mail.onmicrosoft.com' `
            -BadItemLimit 10 -LargeItemLimit 20 
    }
```

Comment: Where are you defining $LocalCred? Could you post the full code? I believe at some place the scope of where your creds are called is being overwritten

Comment: It is at the beginning of the script outside of any function. There are some others commands that need my creds